# Redirecting output to a local USB printer with PHP 4.3

Tags: php, printing, usb

Let's assume I have a few machines running an ancient version of PHP(4.3.5) on Windows XP. At this point upgrading is out of the question. What would be the least intrusive way to make those machines redirect certain output(namely receipts) directly to a local USB printer?

So far my best guess would be writing the output into a local file, and then sending it to the printer through exec().

P.S.: Do not suggest php_printer unless you can provide a proper dll of it(for PHP 4.3, that is).

Comment: What OS is on the server?

Comment: writing a simple app is a nice solution, interfacing with files in one folder.

Comment: 4.3?! I thought my company still on 5.2 was bad. My sympathies go out to your situation :(

Comment: might want to put 4.3 in the headline, it's very short and very important. php changed a lot all these years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's very nice to have web pages (I am assuming you're not using CLI PHP since support was so bad back then) doing too much I/O. That's what daemons are for.

If I were you, I'd:

1. make the PHP page write a file to be printed.
2. A daemon would watch a directory and print when necessary.

PHP is not designed for systems programming. Printing is a long running task, and the page would need to block a long time to see if printing succeeded. That's why I'd prefer the asynchronous approach, which also gives you the opportunity to use another language, which seems like a perfectly rational decision.